# Android Studio icon showing in launchpad but not opening

Tags: 14.04, android-studio

I'm trying to download the Andoid Studio on Ubuntu 14.04, it seems to install no problem but when it tries to run, the icon appears in the launchpad but no program opens up. I have the latest version of java installed and my JAVA_HOME is set to the java folder in both /etc/environment and /.bashrc.

I do have two similar java folders though, one that is java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 and java-7-openjdk-amd64. I have set my PATH variable to both of these folders which have similar contents with no luck. I have a homework assignment due, If anyone can help or knows a resource that can I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it directly from the command line? I had a similar issue with Arduino Studio and that fixed it.

eg.

```
sudo /path/to/andriod/studio
```

Comment: I did. for me its `sudo /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` still no luck

Comment: Aside from the android studio zip package, do I also need to install the android sdk? or is that in the studio package?

Comment: It should be included in the package. I believe the sdk if for if you want to use things like eclipse of other Java editors to make apps